# Assign tags to file via Windows command line?

Tags: command-line, windows-8, windows-7, cmd, tags

It's easy to assign tags to a file in Windows Explorer. (In my case, JPEG files in Windows 7). However, I want to do so in a VBA procedure. I can run a Windows command line through VBA, so my question is:

Is there a way of assigning a tag to a file using a command line (in Windows 7 or later)?

Comment: It isn't quite clear where these tags are stored. If they are file properties, they should be readable or settable with Wmic from the command line. Otherwise there stored in alternative file streams, in that case a pipe should be sufficient. Currently I can't check which one it is, since I can't set tags on images on windows server 2012 R2.

Comment: Can you explain what Wmic is and how I would use it?

Comment: Additionally: in Windows 7 I set the tags on a file by opening Windows Explorer, selecting the file, and clicking the "Add a tag" field in the statusbar at the bottom of the window. (It's also in the Properties dialog).  Can you do that in Windows Server?

Comment: I can see the tags but not change them on windows server.

Comment: Can you explain what Wmic is and how I would use it?

Comment: wmic is the command line interface for the Windows Management Interface (WMI) http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742610.aspx. using the command "wmic datafile ..." one can see metadata of files.